# Why is it OK to not store the result of 'new' in a variable

Tags: java, new-operator

I have been told that the `new` keyword create an instance of a class and **returns an object that is stored in memory and is assigned to a variable of the class type**. If the statement in bold is true, why is the statement below not incorrect?

```
new Class();
```

Because there is no variable assigned to class, while `new` returns a variable?

Comment: In short, the result of the instantiation is immediately discarded once the end of the statement is reached. You haven't given it a variable to be assigned to.

Comment: The compiler will just create a class.. it won't actually do anything with it, nor keep it in any way. The garbage cleaner is deemed to meet it.

Comment: What error are you getting? As mike says, you can have a new X() on a line without assigning the result to a value and it compiles fine.

Comment: `new` will return that address, and it'll simply be thrown away because you're not storing it anywhere. why would this be useful? Consider a singleton/one-shot object where the mere act of instantiating it is all you need to do. no point in saving the object reference, because everything you wanted done was done in the constructor.

Comment: @ mikeTheLiar it is not immediately discarded. If anything happens in the constructor that holds the execution. Also GC will decide when to discard it

Answer (score 10):

Who told you that `new` does what you say it does? `new` creates an object and **returns** the reference to that object. It doesn't assign anything to anyone because the assignment operator in java is `=`

Here's an excerpt from the java tutorial:

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.

[Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Comment: His question is **why is it a valid statement**.

Comment: His statement in bold is not valid, therefore his question is not valid either. In particular this part is incorrect **and is assigned to a variable of the class type.**

Comment: Let me rephrase, the statement `new Class();` is valid, but something like `x + y;` is not valid in Java... In the second case it's a compiler error which asks you to **assign the result to something**...

Comment: Right, because `x+y` is an expression employing an operator.

Comment: Because `new Clazz()` makes sense, having side effects such as execution of the code inside the constructor. However `a+b` has no other side effects if you ignore the result. Therefore it was prohibited by design I think.

Comment: You should mention that in the answer... JLS clearly specifies which statements are valid (and why), you can quote from it..

Answer (score 6):

The "creates an instance of a class and returns the object address that is stored in memory" part is mostly right, except that it's technically Java's own representation of the object's location rather than the actual memory address - "reference" is a better term. The "assign it to variable" part is *not* related to `new` at all; the assignment is done by `=`, e.g. `Class c = new Class()`.

If you don't have a `=`, the address won't be assigned to anything. This is usually pointless since it amounts to throwing the new object away, but it is legal because it is sometimes useful (if the constructor has some side effect that you're interested in). It is also legal to use the reference returned by `new` to call a method, e.g. `new Class().doSomething()`, or to pass it as a parameter: `doSomethingElse(new Class())`.

Answer (score 2):

The above statement is not wrong because the code invoking the constructor is choosing to do nothing with the reference to the object.

Perhaps a project has an all encompassing class used to initiate view behavior. You might choose to instantiate an instance of a custom view class within the main method to mimic this behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass();
}
```

Then in your `MyClass` object:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
         //do stuff here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

new is a Java keyword. It creates a Java object for the class and object address that is stored in memory. It also allocates memory for it on the heap. new is also used for array creation, as arrays are also objects.

Example -

```
int[] intArray = new int[10];
String[][] stringMatrix = new String[5][10];
```